# How can i create a custom CSS for a website hosted on Cloudflare

Tags: css, cloudflare

I want to make a website hosted on Cloudflare more beautiful by adding more css style to it and correcting some layout of some pages that are not good enough.

The challenges i'm having is that i don't know where to start, I logged into the cloudflare settings, theme settings but i didn't see the css of the pages i want to correct. I tried googling it and i couldn't find much help, I only notices that i can add CSS through Add CSS app but i don't know where or how.

Please help me with a link to something to read on how to customize cloudflare pages or tell me how to start it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned the website is hosted on Cloudflare, I'm assuming it's on [Cloudflare Pages](https://dash.cloudflare.com/?to=/:account/pages). You can't edit CSS through Cloudflare. Your code will be in either Github or Gitlab connected with your Pages project. Once you find your code repo, then only you can edit. Any changes should be updated on your Pages.

If your website is not on Pages, then it is on a web server hosted somewhere else. You'll need access to the server in order to make any changes. See the DNS records of your website's domain to find the IP of the server if you're not sure where it is hosted.